# Passing Action<> into Async Method

Tags: c#, asynchronous, async-await, delegates, action

I understand in an async method that *out* and *ref* can not be used. But I am unclear on the consequences of using ***Action*** (or delegates). While I recognize that the value being set in the Action may not be available until after the await, are there any other problems with the below? Are their threading problems? I have googled extensively on this, but can't find clarity anywhere.

```
protected async Task<gPeriod> MapPeriod(string value, Action<int> setOutput)
{
    (...) //omitted code
    int x = await MyMethodAsync(value)
    setOutput(x);
    return gPeriod;  //calculation of this not shown in this example
}
```

Comment: There is nothing inherently wrong or dangerous about the code in the question.

Comment: Your code is fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you always `await` a task, code from programmers point of view works really close to synchronous code. But when you start doing things like this

```
var task1 = FooAsync(setOutput);
var task2 = BarAsync(setOutput);
var result1 = await task1;
var result2 = await task2;
```

things start to get funny, because order they finish or threads they use is not guaranteed.

Anyway your code is fine.